# Storing Data Flutter Internally

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I store data internally, let's say a high score in Flutter so that when the app reboots the high score doesn't go back to 0?

Comment: In most programming languages, you would have to store this in some sort of persistence mechanism, like a file, registry or database.

Comment: You need to use any persistent store. Be sure to check out this official guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to implement it:

- You can check out [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). They allow you to store the score locally as key value pairs for simple functionality.
- If you want more complicated data, you can consider creating a local database.
- If you want online storage, you can use online databases.